# keyboard input not working in linux login?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, linux-kernel, parrot-os

i recently upgraded my parrot security OS from 3.7 to 3.11. The problem is when i boot into it, the os is not detecting keyboard inputs. Hence i cannot enter my password at login and access the system.

However i can access the root terminal from recovery mode.

The contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log show mouse and keyboard disabled.

1. what is the problem?
2. which files am i looking for?
3. what file do i need to update?

Parrot OS is based on debian platform.

contents of Xorg.0.log

```
[    78.543] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[    78.547] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    78.549] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-5-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    78.550] Current Operating System: Linux parrot 4.9.0-parrot18-amd64 #1 SMP Parrot 4.9.18-1parrot18 (2017-04-23) x86_64
[    78.550] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-parrot18-amd64 root=UUID=5c770719-f7be-4f96-b3ae-0694e4e47f5d ro single noautomount
[    78.553] Build Date: 26 January 2018  04:30:21PM
[    78.554] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[    78.556] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    78.558]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    78.558] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    78.564] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Feb  7 09:03:03 2018
[    78.564] (II) Loader magic: 0x55622c77ede0
[    78.564] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    78.564]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    78.564]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    78.564]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    78.564]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    78.565] (--) using VT number 2

[    78.565] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    78.565] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    78.565] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    78.581] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:191b:103c:80a9 rev 6, Mem @ 0x92000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    78.581] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:139a:103c:80a9 rev 162, Mem @ 0x93000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128
[    78.685] List of video drivers:
[    78.690]    nvidia
[    78.694]    modesetting
[    78.694] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    78.700] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    78.773] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    78.773]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    78.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    78.781] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    78.781] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    78.791] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    78.791]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[    78.791]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    78.791]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    78.792] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  387.34  Tue Nov 21 01:38:22 PST 2017
[    78.792] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    78.792] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    79.076] (++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
[    79.078] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    79.100] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[    79.100] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    79.100] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    79.101] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[    79.101] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[    79.101] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[    79.101] (**) |   |-->Device "Card1"
[    79.101] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    79.101] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    79.101] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    79.101] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    79.101] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    79.122] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    79.153] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    79.153]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    79.157] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    79.157]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    79.157] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    79.157] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    79.157] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    79.157] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    79.157] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    79.184] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    79.184] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    79.184] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    79.204] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    79.205]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    79.205]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    79.205] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    79.205] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    79.205] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    79.219] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    79.219]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    79.219]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    79.220] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    79.220] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    79.220] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    79.231] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    79.232] (EE) 
[    79.236] (EE) Backtrace:
[    79.238] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x55622c4f3e3d]
[    79.239] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55622c33c000+0x1bbbd9) [0x55622c4f7bd9]
[    79.241] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7ff8a7429000+0x12160) [0x7ff8a743b160]
[    79.242] (EE) 
[    79.243] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[    79.245] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    79.247] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    79.249] (EE) 
[    79.250] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    79.255] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    79.256] (EE) 
[    79.258] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Guys any solutions,  I really need to get access to the system.  My projects are in it.

Answer (score 0):

Dmesg, check it out to see what it says. If there is a hardware error it should be there.

`dmesg | less`

But that's a classic, right?

Have you also checked /var/log/messages ?

Comment: What am I looking for in messages?

Comment: I have added contents of xorg.log . Have a look. its showing mouse and keyboard disabled.